# What does '^{}' mean in the tags?

Tags: git

When I run `git ls-remote --tags`, I see some output like this:

```
97dd8d7ed4760538f58f5cdeeb32602764545966    refs/tags/3.9.17
fd6fe7a28624ea5a5420f8541279226d66733588    refs/tags/3.9.17^{}
1cb660eb7c5d7c738be52fb4be5daf8427bde37e    refs/tags/3.9.18
a04aa914c37663109773aec75dbf8e89c5048242    refs/tags/3.9.18^{}
```

What does `^{}` mean in the output above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse

> **^{}, e.g. v0.99.8^{}**
>
> A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

I.e. that means that `fd6fe7a...` is nearest non-tag (guess it’s a commit) reachable from tag **3.9.17**.